# How to add new browser extension target to existing react-native app?

Tags: ios, react-native, safari, safari-extension, browser-extension

I have existing React-Native app. I need to create Safari browser extension for iOS and MacOS Safari browser. For extension, I have React.js project for other browser extension. Now I have tried to convert it into Safari extension and It is working fine. But what if I have to add Extension target to existing React-Native app? Which steps I need to follow to add target to iOS app?

Can you please guide me on this? Thank you in advance.